# How to set the default values for the ScaleBar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar, template

I often insert scalebars (that's quite common) in my maps, but the one set by default doesn't suit me at all. Example :

- Reference point : default is up and left i need it down and right
- Segments are set to 2 left and 4 right, I need 2 right only
- Style is simplebox and i need doublebox
- ...

Do you know a way to default this ? It's a bit tedious to change it manually every time...

For additional info : I didn't find anything in Composer - Settings menu/Composer where i thought i might find those info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Save your scalebar as a template.**

---

Create a blank composer, add a scalebar with your relevant settings then from the menubar in your print composer, go to:

```
Composer > Save as Template...
```

The next time you're creating a map, you can use:

```
Composer > Add Items from Template...
```

which will load your scalebar with the options you saved it with.

Comment: That rocks ! Thanks for that tip, I realize I never used that menu item before...hem. Time to massively use it :)

Comment: @RobinP - Most welcome! I have found it useful when tedious tasks began to take its toll on me =)