# Duplicating attributes table within QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, print-composer

I'm working with QGIS 2.14.6-Essen on a Windows 7 OS.

I have added an attributes table in QGIS composer with specific properties (attributes displayed, fonts, frame and background colors, etc.). This table filters data from a layer (`"code" = '086077'`).

Now, I want to add a second attributes table with exactly the same specifications except the filter (`"code" = '086233'`).

Is there a way to duplicate the first table so that I would just have to modifiy the filter value in the duplicated table? So far, I have no other choice than starting from the beginning for my second table...

Comment: Probably the same solution in this post: [How to set the default values for the ScaleBar in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210005/how-to-set-the-default-values-for-the-scalebar-in-qgis) where you create a blank composer, add your attribute table with the specific properties, save it as a template, then load this from the template in your composer. Unfortunately, _Copy/Paste_ doesn't work! =)

Comment: Yep this could do the job! Thanks dear @Jospeh! And hope it will come with a future version.

Comment: Most welcome! Perhaps there is another way to achieve this but for me atleast, that was the easiest. And yes, I also hope it will come in the future ;)